# Android theme style for button not applying

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

I have three simple buttons in my main activity view.
What I am trying to do is apply a buttonstyle to all my buttons but I fail to do so.

Here's my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/minecraft_portrait"
    android:alpha="0.75"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtAppName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/app_name_readable"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCrafting"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:onClick="craftingButtonClicked"
        android:text="@string/crafting" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnServerCommands"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/btnCrafting"
        android:layout_below="@id/btnCrafting"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:onClick="commandsButtonClicked"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="@string/servercommands" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnVideos"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/btnServerCommands"
        android:layout_below="@id/btnServerCommands"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:onClick="videosButtonClicked"
        android:text="@string/videos" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my style.xml from the res/values folder:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonTheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ButtonTheme" parent="android:Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">32sp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And my theme definition from the manifest file:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
....
```

Any ideas why the style isn't applying to my buttons?
I have set the textcolor of one button to white just to see any difference.

Comment: May be your activity overrides app theme.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

When using the support library the button style must be applied as:

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonTheme</item>
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/ButtonTheme</item>
</style>
```

Note the duplication but with no namespace

Comment: It worked! Please Robbie, accept this answer that is very helpful.

Comment: With the support library, only the non-namespaced item is required to make this work. There is no need for duplication

Comment: I can't confirm this for my question since I don't own the source anymore, I know (now) that's how it should be done. Thx

Comment: If you are using Material Components, use the `materialButtonStyle` attribute instead of `buttonStyle`

Answer (score 4):

The code that you post is working. Please add style on button in xml, to see if that is working for you.

```
<Button
    style="@style/ButtonTheme"

    android:id="@+id/btnCrafting"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
    android:onClick="craftingButtonClicked"
    android:text="@string/crafting" />
```

Comment: No the style isn't applying that way either

Comment: Remove android:background="@drawable/button_selector" from button and try again. I am not sure why this is not working. And try it on emulator also.

Comment: This works but I don't want to go through all my code and add this to every button.  I want to add button style to the appTheme in 1 place.

Answer (score 1):

Try running "clean" on the project when changing styles or the manifest file.