# Android Button Theme not applying

Tags: android, android-layout, themes, android-theme, android-styles

I created really simple view. I would like to create default layout for my button and import it via AppTheme, which i added in manifest file.

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/ButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:button">@style/ButtonStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="ButtonStyle" >
        <item name="android:textSize">20dp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">150dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/defaultbutton</item>
</style>
```

So what I expect is to have all buttons in my app be styled which this settings. Only way i can accomplishe it is to import style inside my button using

`style="@style/ButtonStyle"`

Button 'Start Test' is styled via inside import.

Funny thing is that some styles are imported for buttons 'Settings' and 'Check Sensors' ( like *drawable/deefaultbutton* or centered text)

```
<Button
    style="@style/ButtonStyle"
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Start Test" />

<Button

    android:id="@+id/settings"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Settings" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/checkSensors"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Check Sensors" />
```

My question is, why is this happening and i can't set it as default without importing it via 'Theme' ?

Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19707648/android-theme-style-for-button-not-applying) and read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33748406/why-androidbuttonstyle-does-not-style-buttons) but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Custom style should extend `Widget` styles to use with `buttonStyle` attribute.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonStyle">
        <item name="android:textSize">20dp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">150dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/defaultbutton</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Is this the same way a setting up a 'parent'? I've tried parent and your soultion and it is not working for me unfortunately.

Comment: Ok, but this solution doesn't work either :/ Do you have any idea if this is even possible, or i need to style every button by @style inside activity.xml ?